# Problems While Trying To Parse The ID From a Vimeo URL

Tags: javascript, parsing, vimeo

The code that I'm using to get the ID from a Vimeo video is this one:function

```
function vimeo_embed_format(src, width, height) {
  var final_syntax;
  var first_part;
  var second_part;
  var third_part;

  first_part = "<iframe src='http://player.vimeo.com/video/" + src + "' ";
  second_part = "width='" + width + "' height='" + height +"' ";
  third_part = "frameborder='0'></iframe>";
  final_part = first_part + second_part + third_part;

  return final_part;
}

vimeo_id_extract(url) {
  var re;
  var match;
  var final_id;

  re = new RegExp('/[0-9]+', "g");
  match = re.exec(url);

  if(url.toLowerCase().indexOf('vimeo') > 0) {
    if (match == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return match[0].substring(1);
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
function vimeo_do(video, width, height) {
  var make_syntax;
  var regexp_url;

  regexp_url = /((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\:\/\/){1}\S+)/;

  if(regexp_url.test(video) == false) {
    make_syntax = vimeo_embed_format(vimeo_id_extract(video), width, height);
  } else {
    make_syntax = vimeo_embed_format(video, width, height);
  }

  document.writeln(make_syntax);
}
```

The problem is that it returns me `undefined`. What should I do to correct?

Comment: @Basiclife: http://vimeo.com/18890010

Comment: no `http://` or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this `if(url.toLowerCase().indexOf('vimeo') > 0)` if you're url is `vimeo.com/idnro` then the index of `vimeo` in the url is 0. Also you'd probably want to modify you're regex to be `re = new RegExp('[0-9]+$')` to account for urls like

```
http://vimeo.com/groups/687/videos/3741327
```

Otherwise you'll match 687 and not the actual video id. I also highly recommend [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) for debugging stuff like this. It's a gem.

**UPDATE**

Assuming an ill formed URL will go into `vimeo_id_extract` this is what I would do. Firstly return a number on both occasions from the `vimeo_id_extract` and check that the number returned is not invalid. If not then everything should be fine, otherwise there was no video id in the url.

If you know that the video id will always terminate the string then add a `$` sign to the end of the regex to make sure that the last seven digit sequence is extracted.

```
function vimeo_id_extract(url) {
  var re;
  var match;
  re = new RegExp('[0-9]{7}');
  match = re.exec(url);
  if(match != null) {
    return match[0];
  }
  else {
    return -1;
  }
}

function vimeo_do(video, width, height) {
  var make_syntax;
  var regexp_url;

  regexp_url = /((mailto\:|(news|(ht|f)tp(s?))\:\/\/){1}\S+)/;

  if(regexp_url.test(video) == false) {
    vimeo_id = vimeo_id_extract(video)
    if vimeo_id != -1 {
      make_syntax = vimeo_embed_format(vimeo_id_extract(video), width, height);
    }
    else {
      // there is no video id in the string passed in
    }
  } else {
    make_syntax = vimeo_embed_format(video, width, height);
  }

  document.writeln(make_syntax);
}
```

Comment: So what should I change on the `if` statement?

Comment: @Nathan: see edits above. The regex will fail by the way if there are some query string stuff in the url. I couldn't find any on vimeo that had, but you never know. So a final tweak might be change it to `/([0-9]+)` and have the return be `return match[1]`

Comment: It works now, but when I put just the ID, I get the same `undefined` stuff :/

Comment: @Nathan: Naturally, since there is no `'vimeo'` string in the url you pass in. Why are you checking if Vimeo exists in the URL? Could you specify all the different versions of the url patterns that can be passed in?

Comment: @Matti: See how I made it in the second snippet :)

Comment: @Nathan: Right, well assuming that any invalid url be passed in with no guarantees that `vimeo` will even appear in the url, then I'm afraid you're down to matching the id. See update above.

Comment: You shouldn't assume all video urls have 7 digits. The ones on the front page are 8 for example, and I'm sure you can find ones with less than 7. At least make it {7,} as a short-term fix.